# How to prefer font that is loaded by AddFontMemResourceEx than system?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm developing game application on windows by C++ with the font that is included in resource.

I can load the font by `AddFontMemResourceEx` and `CreateFont`.
And, I can render text with loaded font correctly in my environment that doesn't install any special font.

But, several version of the font exists in the world.
If other version was already installed in system, `CreateFont` will find font by the font name(`pszFaceName`) and prefer system font inconveniently.
Is there anyway to prefer private font that is loaded by `AddFontMemResourceEx`?

FYI, The return value of `AddFontMemResourceEx` is `HANDLE`, but I can't find any code that use it for `CreateFont`.
Probably, edit font family on private font can avoid conflict.
But, I want to resolve by programming if I can.

```cpp
HANDLE handle = AddFontMemResourceEx(data, readBytes, NULL, &fontNum);

hFont = CreateFont(24, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, SHIFTJIS_CHARSET, OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS,
                   CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, L"UmePlus CL Gothic");
```

Comment: The only thing the `HANDLE` returned by `AddFontMemResourceEx()` can be used for is `RemoveFontMemResourceEx()` There is no way (that I know of) to prefer the memory font over other fonts that may be installed. There is only 1 font table in the system, `CreateFont(Indirect)()` loads the most appropriate font it can find for the characteristics that you specify. If another font is a better match than your memory font, well then so be it.

Comment: You could change the face name of the font dynamically in-memory, before calling `AddFontMemResourceEx`. You would have to make a copy of the resource data to be able to write to it. [OpenType specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for comments!
I've replaced font name in memory based on comment.

But, this code has bit complicacy by difference of endian.

Caution: `newFontName` must be shorter than `oldFontName`.

```cpp
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct {
    short version;
    long numTables;
    short searchRange;
    short entrySelector;
    short rangeShift;
} TTF_HEADER;

typedef struct {
    char name[4];
    long checksum;
    long offset;
    long length;
} TTF_OFFSET_TABLE;

typedef struct {
    short format;
    short count;
    short stringOffset;
} TTF_NAME_TABLE_HEADER;

typedef struct {
    short platformId;
    short specificId;
    short languageId;
    short nameId;
    short length;
    short offset;
} TTF_NAME_TABLE_ENTRY;
#pragma pack()

void copySwappedWchar(const wchar_t* src, wchar_t* dest, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dest[i] = _byteswap_ushort(src[i]);
    }
}

void renameLocalFont(unsigned char* data, const wchar_t* oldFontName, const wchar_t* newFontName) {
    TTF_HEADER* header = (TTF_HEADER*)data;
    unsigned char* offsetTableBase = data + sizeof(TTF_HEADER);
    for (int i = 0; i < _byteswap_ulong(header->numTables); i++) {
        TTF_OFFSET_TABLE* table = (TTF_OFFSET_TABLE*)(offsetTableBase + sizeof(TTF_OFFSET_TABLE) * i);
        if (memcmp(table->name, "name", 4) != 0) continue;

        TTF_NAME_TABLE_HEADER* nameTable = (TTF_NAME_TABLE_HEADER*)(data + _byteswap_ulong(table->offset));
        unsigned char* entryBase = data + _byteswap_ulong(table->offset) + sizeof(TTF_NAME_TABLE_HEADER);
        for (int j = 0; j < _byteswap_ushort(nameTable->count); j++) {
            TTF_NAME_TABLE_ENTRY* entry = (TTF_NAME_TABLE_ENTRY*)(entryBase + sizeof(TTF_NAME_TABLE_ENTRY) * j);
            wchar_t* dest = new wchar_t[_byteswap_ushort(entry->length) + 1];
            wchar_t* src = (wchar_t*)(data + _byteswap_ulong(table->offset) + _byteswap_ushort(nameTable->stringOffset) + _byteswap_ushort(entry->offset));
            copySwappedWchar((const wchar_t*)src, dest, _byteswap_ushort(entry->length) + 1);
            if (wcscmp(dest, oldFontName) == 0) {
                copySwappedWchar(newFontName, src, wcslen(newFontName) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```